# SDK Version upgrade, and flutter upgrade issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am encountering an issue where, despite attempting multiple solutions like updating, cleaning, and deleting `pubspec.lock` file, I still receive an error when running `flutter pub get` from the terminal. The error output displays Dart SDK version 3.0.1, however running `pub get` from my `pubspec.yaml` file causes the following error:

> The current Dart SDK version is 2.18.2.
>
> Because book_my_guide depends on http >=0.13.6 which requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0 or ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
>
> pub get failed (1; Because book_my_guide depends on http >=0.13.6 which requires SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0 or ^3.0.0, version solving failed.)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

The **book_my_guide** plugin you used is expecting dart SDK version >=2.19.0 <3.0.0. you should upgrade your dart version to use the plugin.

current stable dart version - v3.0.0
your dart version - v2.18.2

just run **flutter upgrade** command to move to stable.

Comment: Sir i have upgraded already, but problem is still same even i did reverse after upgrading but problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

change this in your pubspac.yaml file

environment:
sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"